# Nutanix Cluster Report

Tags: powershell, nutanix

How can i fetch the cluster report from the Nutanix prism portal using powershell (API or module)?

I need to fetch the cluster details like total capacity, free capacity, usage capacity etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few options, one of them would be using:

- The Nutanix Documentation Script: https://carlwebster.com/downloads/download-info/nutanix/
- Nutanix VM reporting script: https://magander.se/nutanix-ahv-vm-reporting-via-rest-api-version-2-4/

Alternatively there's nutanix.dev with a whole bunch of examples you can use to get this kickstarted

disclaimer: I'm a Nutanix employee and author of the script in the first link.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these links but they are not working as expected with my requirement. I need to create the report for the multiple clusters data like cluster CPU usage, free space etc.

Comment: As said, these scripts would be a base for what you'd need as your requirements aren't clear from your post. These scripts together with the ones on nutanix.dev could help you get kickstarted (look at https://www.nutanix.dev/code_samples/nutanix-cluster-info-script/ for example)

Comment: Hi Kees, The link which is provided by you it does not provides the solution of my problem statement. My question is like that how can i fetch the all clusters data like CPU, usage, Free space from the Nutanix Prism central tool itself. Manually we are going to the Operations then reports and then i need to generate the new report based on the requirements and select all the clusters and saving is report in the last step.